# Double Sapply nested function

Tags: r

I am very new to R. Can someone kindly tell me what is going on in the following code.

```
a<- 1:10
b<-sapply(a, function(x) sapply(a,function(y) x+y))
b
```

Why does b look like this:

```
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10    11
 [2,]    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11    12
 [3,]    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12    13
 [4,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13    14
 [5,]    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14    15
 [6,]    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15    16
 [7,]    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16    17
 [8,]    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17    18
 [9,]   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18    19
[10,]   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19    20
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By the time the individual items of two versions of the `a`-vector arrive at the inner expression, they cover the range of the possible pairings of  the first 10 positive integers. It's basically the same as two nested for-loops. The `sapply` function will return a matrix if possible. The inner `sapply` returns a series of length 10 vectors and the outer `sapply` assembles the vectors into a matrix. You could also have returned the same result with:

```
 outer( 1:10, 1:10, "+")
```

I do not really agree with Scriven that this form is "nonsense". If one were using the `sum` function, then the `outer` strategy would not succeed. The `sum` function is not 'vectorized' (at least in the way that function is used by R users) since it does usually not return a value of the same length as its arguments. Nonetheless the double-`sapply` approach would give the same results with `sum(x,y)` as the inner expression, whereas `outer(a,a,'sum')` will fail.